# My HMACSHA1 Digest Doesn't Match What Twitter Has for Oauth 1.0a

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, hmacsha1

I'm trying to do the Oauth 1.0a for Twitter REST API in Android Java following the instructions at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature. I can reproduce the signature base exactly as shown in the guide.

`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nouce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%2520signed%2520OAuth%2520request%2521`

The signing key also matches exactly. But when I use the following code to generate the HMAC-SHA1 digest what I have in hex is different from what is shown on the guide.

```
private String hmac_sha1(String Base, String Key){

    Mac mac;
    try {
        mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(Key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(Base.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        Log.i("hex",bytesToHex(digest));

        return Base64.encodeToString(digest, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        //return new String(Base64.encode(digest,Base64.NO_WRAP));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "";
}
```

I get 
`13 5D F8 C7 60 27 D5 26 69 23 D2 C3 05 A1 68 5C B3 1F 55 4B`
instead of what Twitter Guide has 
`B6 79 C0 AF 18 F4 E9 C5 87 AB 8E 20 0A CD 4E 48 A9 3F 8C B6`

Is there something obvious that I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I misspelled nonce in my code ... I had nouce instead of nonce. After correcting for that everything matches.